# spring-security-saml missing jar in repo

Tags: maven, spring-security, spring-saml

As per the instructions on http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/, I have the following in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

When I execute mvn clean install -U, I receive the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproj: Could not resolve dependencies
for project com.acme.myproj:myproj:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.
springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml:jar:1.0.0.RC2 in spring
-milestones (http://repo.spring.io/milestone) -> [Help 1]

The repo is there at http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/security/extensions/spring-security-saml/1.0.0.RC2/, but there is no .jar file.

Answer (score 3):

The correct dependency to use is:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The jar is available both in Maven Central and http://repo.spring.io/list/release/

The Spring SAML web will get fixed soon.

Comment: Thank you. Could you update the project page (http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/)?

Comment: Dependency in the Spring Security SAML Quick Start is still broken. (if I just knew how to contact somebody from Spring Security ...)